# Chown directory via SSH on server using NPM script

Tags: bash, ssh, chmod, chown

I am trying to chown a directory via an NPM script. The script looks like  the following:

`chown -R 755 www-data root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:/var/www/test.com`

But the message I get back is: **chown: www-data: No such file or directory** even though this exists. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chown` operates locally, not on remote servers. In your example, `chown` is attempting to operate on `./www-data` and `./root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:/var/www/test.com`, which don't exist in the directory of wherever you were when you executed the command.

You will need to execute `chown` as a command through `ssh`:

`ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX chmod -R 755 /var/www/test.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with following script.

`ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX chmod -R 755 /var/www/test.com/`

(I needed to login to the server first).